# What's the proper way to format "if" statements in Java with multiline "ands" or "ors"?

Tags: java, if-statement, format

Apparently "if", "and", and "or" are such generic search parameters that I can't find the answer on google for my life.  Which of these is the correct format according to the Java standards?

**Option 1**:

```
if (condition1
    && condition2
    && condition3) ...
```

or **Option 2**:

```
if (condition1 &&
    condition2 &&
    condition3) ...
```

Comment: Ask 10 people, get 10 answers.

Comment: If you're working alone: whatever you like. If you're working in a group: whatever the group decides.

Comment: To expand on what Taylor is saying... I'd think that with Option 1, the `&&` lines should be shifted 3 characters right so the left-most character of every condition lines up (in the same way that Option 2 does).

Comment: Vote to close - opinion based. It is all personal preference.

Comment: Java has a standard for everything... surely they have a best practices for this documented somewhere...

Comment: @nhgrif See, I would have put three spaces before `condition1` so that the conditions align _and_ are properly indented. :)

Comment: Code Complete has a decent argument for Option 2.  (That said, I'm flagging this as opinion based.)

Comment: Just don't put multiline condition in the if statement. Make it a meaningful named variable and calculate values in in prior the conditional constructer.

Comment: @Taylor  You mean "...10 DIFFERENT answers."

Comment: This question is NOT opinion based.  The question asks what the Java standards say - and the answer is a matter of FACT, not of opinion.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem There is no such standard. The 1997 document Sun brought out (and never updated!) was their internal code style guide for JVM/Java development, not a standard how Java should be formatted by everyone. So, you either get people claiming that that Sun document is a standard (it is not), or people claiming the Google style guide is the standard (it is not), or the default formatting of IntelliJ, NetBeans, or Eclipse, etc. There is no standard, so every answer is an opinion, hence the close is valid.

Answer (score 91, accepted):

The Oracle/Sun guidelines ("Code Conventions for the Java TM Programming Language") tell us to break before an operator.  And they give this example.

```
if ((condition1 && condition2)
        || (condition3 && condition4)
        ||!(condition5 && condition6)) {
    doSomethingAboutIt();
}
```

Many companies that I've worked for adopt the Oracle/Sun guidelines as the standard for their own code.

Refer http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-136091.html#248

Comment: Thank you, I'm aware most people thought this was an opinion-based question, but this was exactly what I was looking for

Comment: However, I'm fairly confident that one could find an "authoritative" source that says just the opposite.

Comment: These are the Java standards, written by Sun, published by Oracle.  This is the horse's mouth.  Any other source is, by definition, less authortitative than this.

Comment: No, because they're just suggestions, and this one has far from universal support (unlike, say, their suggestions for braces). If you work at a company that has a different style, that's more authoritative than this. Heck, I'd say that this guideline is so non-universal that if you prefer a different style, _that's_ more authoritative than this. Of course, you may disagree with the above -- which is why it's an opinion-based question.

Comment: Oh sure, I'm not disputing that lots of companies have their own standards that vary from the Oracle ones, and that lots of developers choose to ignore the Oracle standards.  But the question inquired about what the Java standards are; not about what developers actually do in the real world.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the correct answer is `<CTRL>+<SHIFT>+F` in Eclipse :)

Comment: *I* believe the correct answer is `CTRL` + `ALT` + `L` *in IntelliJ*. ;)

Comment: @BradTurek IntelliJ doesn't format line breaks ;).

Comment: or `ALT`+`SHIFT`+`F` in netbeans

Comment: from normal mode: `gg` + `v` + `shift + g` + `=` in vim ;)

Comment: Which appears to use Option 1.

Answer (score 1):

This is completely subjective.  Coding standards vary from shop to shop.  To steal from yshavit's comment:  Do whatever you want unless you are working in a team environment, in which case you should follow the team standards.

I'm a fan of the second pattern.