# Best practice with lines longer than 80char?

Tags: java, syntax, refactoring, processing

wondering if there's a way to refactor the below line of code to less than 80char?

```
if(swat[i]==0 && 0 <= mouseX-fX[i] && mouseX-fX[i] <= flysize && 0 <= mouseY-fY[i] && mouseY-fY[i] <= flysize){
```

or whether it's best practice to write it as multiple lines like so:

```
if(swat[i]==0
&& 0 <= mouseX-fX[i] && mouseX-fX[i] <= flysize
&& 0 <= mouseY-fY[i] && mouseY-fY[i] <= flysize){
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prefer the second solution. 
I'll even go for a dedicated method, if you need to check this condition in multiple places.

Answer (score 0):

I would lay it out like this:

```
if (swat[i] == 0 && 0 <= mouseX-fX[i] && mouseX-fX[i] <= flysize
                 && 0 <= mouseY-fY[i] && mouseY-fY[i] <= flysize) {
    // code here
}
```

Having the extra spaces for indentation helps to keep the `if` expression distinct from the code inside the block.

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to how to break the statement up, I'm sure many people would answer differently.

Try your best to make it readable, however [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19825746/whats-the-proper-way-to-format-if-statements-in-java-with-multiline-ands-or) question details different approaches to splitting up a line of code. The selected answer has Oracle's recommendation.

Also so long as you aren't repeating this same conditional statement elsewhere in your code, I think it's more readable to store the result in a variable like so:

```java
boolean condition = swat[i]==0 && 0 <= mouseX-fX[i]
    && mouseX-fX[i] <= flysize && 0 <= mouseY-fY[i]
    && mouseY-fY[i] <= flysize;

if (condition) { 
    //code here...
}
```

The above example follows Oracle recommendations of inserting a line break before an operator.

Comment: The question was how to make the code lines not exceed 80 characters, so just moving the long line is not the answer.

Comment: Hi @Andreas, the first part of the answer was to make long conditional statements more readable. The second part of the answer does answer the question.

Comment: I'll go ahead and switch the order in that I say those things.

Comment: Don't just *say* "you can make the condition multiline", **show it**. Having the only shown example still be a long line is less than useful.

Comment: Fair enough. How does that look?

Answer (score 0):

*I'm answering in terms of Google's practices and tools here. Other practices and tools are available; these are the ones I'm most familiar with, and find work just fine.*

Questions of "best practice" tend to be somewhat opinion-based.

Personally, I would say that a column limit is a good thing, because it stops lines just rambling on and on and on... But there is no clear reason why 80 characters would be the "correct" limit; for example, [Google's Java style guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html) specifies a 100-character limit.

I consider that formatting is something that's best left to an objective tool. Choices around formatting are largely uninteresting, provided they end up producing readable code; a tool can apply rules consistently, and leave you free to do more interesting things.

Using Google's formatting tool, [google-java-format](https://github.com/google/google-java-format), your code is formatted like so:

```
if (swat[i] == 0
    && 0 <= mouseX - fX[i]
    && mouseX - fX[i] <= flysize
    && 0 <= mouseY - fY[i]  
    && mouseY - fY[i] <= flysize) {
```

which I find preferable to the first way. However, I recognize that the second and third conditions are related, and the fourth and fifth are related. You can achieve this grouping with parentheses:

```
if (swat[i] == 0
    && (0 <= mouseX - fX[i] && mouseX - fX[i] <= flysize)
    && (0 <= mouseY - fY[i] && mouseY - fY[i] <= flysize)) {
```

which I think is better again.

You may rail against having to change the code in order to get the formatter to do something in a particular way; honestly, the value of simple formatting rules and a tool to consistently applies them far outweighs the cost of a couple of pairs of parentheses (I don't remember the last time I found I had to did this "for real").